# issue plotting excel data in r shiny - issue object server not found

Tags: shiny

I have an Excel spread sheet containing 2 columns "Alpha1" and "Beta2".

I would like to plot each column on a histogram using R shiny. Below is my code:

```
install.packages("shiny","magrittr", "ggplot2")
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)  

data<-read.csv(file='testdata.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep=",")

ui<-fluidPage("data", 
              #define UI, 
              titlePanel(title="Excel data"), 
              selectInput("data$Alpha1", "data$Beta2"), 
              mainPanel("excel data main panel", 
                        plotOutput("data$Alpha1"), 
                        plotOutput("data$Beta2"))
              )

server<-function(input,output) {

    output$data <- renderPlot({plot(data$Alpha1), 
                               plot(data$Beta2)})
})
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Would anyone be able to pin point why this is not working?

I am also getting an error:

> Error in shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) : object 'server' not found

Comment: You have defined you plotOutput name as data$Alpha1 but you never assign anything to that name. Change it to plotOutput("data")

Comment: Also, each plotOutput only holds one plot, while you are putting two in the same output

Comment: Hi @Mark thank you for responding.

Alpha1 is one of the column names in my excel table which I have assigned to the name 'data'. 

I know using the $ to reference a column name works in r studio, but is r shiny different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code suggests a lack of fundamental understanding of how Shiny works.  All UI inputs (`selectInput`,`numericInput`,etc...) all have `inputId`'s which are used in the server layer via `input` while all UI outputs (`plotOutput`,`verbatimOutput`, etc...) all have `outputId`'s which are used in the server layer via `output`.  These Id's are character strings that are treated like column names in a data.frame (where the data.frame is either `input` or `output`).

So there's a lot wrong with the code you have so I'm going to break down your code one bit a time and explain what's wrong.  Since I don't have your dataset, I'm going to use this for data

```
data<-data.frame(Alpha1 = runif(100),Beta2 = rnorm(100))
```

From `?fluidPage` we see that it first takes `...` and has a few named arguments, `title` being one of them.  So the random `"data"` you have floating at the beginning needs to become `title="data"`.

Next, `?selectInput` needs three things - an `inputId`, `label` and `choices`.  The `inputId` is how you will reference the UI object in your server.  So, `selectInput('si1','First Select Input',list(choice1="Choice 1", choice2="Choice 2")` will produce a dropdown box with a visible label "First Select Input" and choices.  In the server part of your code, you'll be able to reference it with `input$si1`.

Now, you have two `plotOutput`'s.  From `?plotOutput` we see the first argument is the `outputId`.  So, `plotOutput('Alpha1')` will be referenced on the server side as `output$Alpha1`.  Where you have `plotOutput("data$Alpha1")` you've created a label which has to be referenced as

```
output$`data$Alpha1`
```

Finally, you have two `plotOutput` but only one `renderPlot`, you need one for each `plotOutput`.  Also, each `renderPlot` can only produce one plot, so making multiple will only return the last one (like how functions in R automatically return the last line).

Put this all together and you have the code below:

```
ui<-fluidPage(title = "data", 
          titlePanel(title="Excel data"), 
          selectInput("si1","Select Column",list("Alpha1", "Beta2")), 
          mainPanel("excel data main panel", 
                    plotOutput("Alpha1"), 
                    plotOutput("Beta2"))
)

server<-function(input,output) {
  output$Alpha1 <- renderPlot({plot(data$Alpha1)})
  output$Beta2 <- renderPlot({plot(data$Beta2)})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative and clear post, Mark. I definitely need to increase my understanding of R shiny. I have completed online several online tutorials, but still cannot grasp it. This code is part of a college assignment I must complete. I must also figure out how to plot these 2 excel columns "Alpha1" and "Beta2" on a scatter plot that the user can change the axes on. As a professional who works with r shiny are there any resources (online or written) you could recommend? Thank you so much, and kind regards, Sinead